# Vec<T>のイテレータを消費するには

Tags: rust

次のように，`Vec<T>::iter()`をイテレータを消費する関数`consume()`に対して渡したいのですが，

```
fn consume<T: Iterator<Item=char>>(input: &mut T){
    unimplemented!()
}

fn main(){
    let mut buffer = vec!['a','b','c'];
    consume(&mut buffer.iter()); //type mismatch
}
```

次のようなコンパイルエラーが生じます．

```
prog.rs:7:5: 7:12 error: type mismatch resolving `<core::slice::Iter<'_, char> as core::iter::Iterator>::Item == char`:
  expected &-ptr,
found char [E0271]
```

`buffer`は`consume()`の呼出し後は破壊されても構いません．どのように書くのが良いでしょうか．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vecが消費されて困る場合は、`cloned`メソッドを使ってイテレーターを複製してください。

```
fn consume<T: Iterator<Item=char>>(input: T){
    unimplemented!()
}

fn main(){
    let buffer = vec!['a','b','c'];
    consume(buffer.iter().cloned());
}
```

Vecが消費されてもよい場合であれば、`into_iter`メソッドを使ってイテレーターに変換します。

```
fn consume<T: Iterator<Item=char>>(input: T){
    unimplemented!()
}

fn main(){
    let buffer = vec!['a','b','c'];
    consume(buffer.into_iter());
}
```